Unable to Set NumberFormat to "DZD" in VBA for Specific Rows
I am encountering an issue with setting the number format to "DZD" for specific rows in VBA. Here's the relevant part of my code:
For rowNumber = 6 To 15
    ' Set the currency symbol for the row
    If rowNumber = 6 Or rowNumber = 7 Or rowNumber = 9 Or rowNumber = 10 Or rowNumber = 12 Then
        wsMap.Rows(rowNumber).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
    Else
        wsMap.Rows(rowNumber).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 DZD" ' This line causes an error
    End If
Next rowNumber


In this loop, I'm trying to set the number format for rows 6 to 15 in a worksheet (wsMap). If the row number is 6, 7, 9, 10, or 12, I set the number format to display the currency symbol as "$". This part of the code works fine. However, when I try to set the number format to display the currency symbol as "DZD" for other rows, I encounter an error.
The error message I receive is: "Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class."
I've tried different approaches, such as setting the number format individually for each cell in the row, but I keep encountering the same error. Can anyone help me understand why setting the number format to "DZD" is causing an error, and how I can resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I tried the following code
For rowNumber = 6 To 15
    ' Set the currency symbol for the row
    If rowNumber = 6 Or rowNumber = 7 Or rowNumber = 9 Or rowNumber = 10 Or rowNumber = 12 Then
        wsMap.Rows(rowNumber).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
    Else
        wsMap.Rows(rowNumber).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 AED" ' This line causes an error
    End If
Next rowNumber


it works with $ symbole but gives error with 'AED' symbole

Are you looking for "#,##0.00 ""AED""" or "#,##0.00 ""DZD"""?
